# Entity Framework: DataTable as XML string

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, datatable

I'm currently storing the data of my application using a simple binary formatter. I'd like to move from the binary formatter to a SQL implementation, for the following reasons:

- Enable concurrent use of the application on a common data source
- Moving away from a 'proprietary' format that can easily corrupt and potentially be inaccessible from other platforms/applications (even other assemblies)

I'm implementing Entity Framework code first to design my database. My question revolves around the storage of DataTable fields. Say I have the following object:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DataTable TableOfInformation {get;set;}
}
```

Saving the string "Name" to a column is simple enough. In order to save the DataTable, I've tried converting to a list of datatable entries. Currently I'm leaning towards simply using XML serialization and saving the DataTable as a string column.

Is this the best way of saving a DataTable field, and are there any concerns with this approach?

Comment: DataTable is really ,not designed for using it with EF. Just deserialize your data into POCO object which will much more work easily with Code First.

Comment: You should take this one step further and also store the DataTable as a database table.

Comment: You can convert DataTable to XML with [DataTable.WriteXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. However, this is anyway the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend storing a `DataTable` as a field.. it makes more sense to create an actual table instead. That being said, if you still wish to proceed with this, it's not that difficult really. Here's an example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string TableOfInformationXml { get; set; }

    [NotMapped] // <-- This is important, since you will only store the TableOfInformationXml field
    public DataTable TableOfInformation
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TableOfInformationXml))
            {
                return new DataTable();
            }
            var set = new DataSet();
            using (var reader = new StringReader(TableOfInformationXml))
            {
                set.ReadXml(reader);
            }
            return set.Tables[0];
        }
        set
        {
            var set = new DataSet();
            set.Tables.Add(value);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(sb))
            {
                set.WriteXml(stringWriter);
            }
            TableOfInformationXml = sb.ToString(); 
        }
    }
}
```

And FYI: You might also consider storing it as JSON instead of XML... in which case, use the following :

```
[NotMapped]
public DataTable TableOfInformation
{
    get
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TableOfInformationJson))
        {
            return new DataTable();
        }
        return TableOfInformationJson.JsonDeserialize<DataTable>();
    }
    set { TableOfInformationJson = value.ToJson(); }
}
```

Here I have 2 extension methods as follows:

```
public static string ToJson<T>(this T item)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
}

public static T JsonDeserialize<T>(this string json)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I understand that this is not ideal from an indexing perspective, or ensuring that all the data in the database is queryable. However I don't know of a simple and easy to implement way to rather create an actual table instead. The DataTable can be any dimension (depends on the user, and I don't know beforehand), and can change dimension size in the application. One class can also have multiple tables, and I'd like to be able to manage them easily. Is there a reason why I should rather consider JSON (is it more platform independent)?

Comment: @User_FSharp1123, I'm not sure what you mean regarding dimension size. As for JSON vs XML, there's no big difference really, except that JSON will surely take up less space. As for performance, I honestly couldn't say whether serializing/deserializing JSON would be any quicker than doing so with XML.. you may be able to find some info online about that or make some kind of console test app to investigate it further. Other than that, it would just be a matter of personal preference really, I suppose.

Comment: So what I mean by dimension size, is that I do not see how I can follow the approach specified by Amadeus, as it would need to have a property for each column in the DataTable (rows obviously won't be a problem). I however do not know how many columns there will be (could be 10, could be 100, it's user-dependent), as so that is why I think the solution as you have set out here makes more sense. I'm keen to go for the XML approach, as it seems that it's easy to parse in both .NET and in the SQL database.

Comment: @User_FSharp1123, sure thing... just remember to mark this as the answer if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model that has all the fields in your DataTable.

```
public class PersonData
{
  public string Address { get; set;}
  public bool IsStackOverflowUser {get; set;}
  public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can add a PersonData property to your Person model

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public PersonData PersonalInformation {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: So although this would be the ideal situation, I don't know the fields in the DataTable to that extent. They are created dynamically, as it is a 2-dimensional data structure containing doubles, i.e. can be 10x4, or 20x6, or whatever the case may be. The dimension can also change for a specific instance of the Person class (changing from 10x4 to 10x6 for example).

Comment: Important to also note that it doesn't contain only doubles (as otherwise I would've used an array), but contains a combination of strings and double/int values. The Person class will be part of a hierarchy (e.g. Parent, GrandParent, Siblings), of which each class can contain multiple DataTables not necessarily of the same dimension.

Comment: That sounds like a case for [ExpandoObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx). You can try to parse all of the cell contents as strings and then use the [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) methods to parse any int or doubles that are in the DataTable.